# Can a past participle be used as a post-modifier?

Tags: adjectives, past-participles, post-modifier

> The slum dwellers are often seen
>    quarreling with each other which seriously
>    affects the psychology of the children **belonged** to those families.

I doubt about its use as a post modifier, if any objection please say.

Comment: *belonging to those families* or simply "in those families".  Also, a minor quibble: it isn't the being seen quarreling, but the quarreling, which affects their psychology.

Comment: Thanx,but I didn't understand your later objection. If I say -The slum dwellers quarrel with each other and seeing such incident their children get psychologically affected.
Is there any mistake?if not..doesn't my sentence(in question) imply to the same meaning?

Comment: OK. Your use of the passive voice ("are often seen quarreling") did not make clear that it was the *children* who were seeing the people quarrel. So, let's rearrange the sentence: *The psychology of children living in these slums is adversely affected by their witnessing the frequent quarrels that break out among the adults in the family.*  (or "among the adults in their families")

Answer (score 2):

The use is not correct. Rather than try to force the word "belonged," where it really does not (ahem) belong, I would offer this rewrite:

"...psychology of those families' children."

Again, an analytical struggle over a single word often hints at a structual problem in the sentence rather than with the word itself.